Dropper Post on Marlin 7 Gen 2 (2021)
I am looking to install a dropper post on my Trek Marlin 7 Gen 2 (2021) size XL. I am thinking I want to get a PNW Cascade 150mm. When I went to measure the seatpost to make sure, it stopped before the slight bend in the tube. I believe this is caused by the bottle cage bolts. From searching online, I have read that there may be a piece holding them in from inside the tube, can I remove the bolts at home or should I go to my local shop?
--
thumbdrive

Are you asking if you can remove the bolts or remove the eyelets into which the bolts thread?

Does the 125mm fit?  If you can, better to find a seat post that meets you needs than modify the frame.

Is the frame built for an internally routed dropper cable? I wasn't sure if there was space to route it internally or not .

I think the threaded nuts in the seat-tube are nut-serts, which are usually riveted in place. I would take it to the bicycle shop.
I've never used a dropper post but since they have height adjustment, wouldn't one of the PNW models fit into your frame without having to remove the bottle cage nut-serts?
Going by the PNW Cascade webpage diagram the 150mm model, at the minimum insertion into your seat-tube, 110mm, you would have approx.340mm of seat-post above the seat-tube clamp. (E-D+B) 245-110+205=340
For the PNW Cascade 125 mm at the minimum insertion 90mm, you would have approx. 310mm of seat-post above the seat-tube clamp. (E-D+B) 215-90+185=310


Thank you so much! I have no idea what I was thinking. For some reason, I had been measuring from the wrong point in the seatpost, which made me think It was too short and that I needed to remove the threaded nuts. I went back this afternoon and measured from within the seatpost itself and discovered that In in fact do have enough space for the 150 mil dropper.

Hi Thumbdrive, as long as you have 110mm between your seat tube clamp and the highest threaded nut on your seat tube then it will clear the bottle nuts.
